# How to create dynamic react component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to dynamically create react components.

**Original code.**

```
class RenderTester extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { 
                 "a":"yay"
            };
        }

        render() {
            return (<div>
                 {this.state.a}
            </div>)
        }
    }
```

**Transpiled code**

```
 result =        window._createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

window._classCallCheck = function(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

window._possibleConstructorReturn = function(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

window._inherits = function(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

window._inheritsRenderTester = function (_Component) {
    window._inherits(RenderTester, _Component);

    function RenderTester(props) {
        _classCallCheck(this, RenderTester);

        var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (RenderTester.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(RenderTester)).call(this, props));

        _this.state = {
            "a": "yay"
        };
        return _this;
    }

    _createClass(RenderTester, [{
        key: "render",
        value: function render() {

            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                this.state.a
            );
        }
    }]);

    return RenderTester;
}(Component);
```

**Usage in JSX**

```
                    <h1>
                        {eval(result)}
                    </h1>
```

I want to render RenderTester inside the JSX but I get the following error:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: Can you include the original code instead of the transpiled code?

Comment: Why would you paste a transpired code?

Comment: Made the changes. I'm trying to create components dynamically rather than creating them in filesystem. 

Feel free to let me know if the title makes sense, or provide suggestions if it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

> **1. Make the transpiled code as a string**

```
let result = `window._createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

window._classCallCheck = function(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

window._possibleConstructorReturn = function(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

window._inherits = function(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

window._inheritsRenderTester = function (_Component) {
    window._inherits(RenderTester, _Component);

    function RenderTester(props) {
        _classCallCheck(this, RenderTester);

        var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (RenderTester.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(RenderTester)).call(this, props));

        _this.state = {
            "a": "yay"
        };
        return _this;
    }

    _createClass(RenderTester, [{
        key: "render",
        value: function render() {

            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                this.state.a
            );
        }
    }]);

    return RenderTester;
}(Component);`
```

> **2. Evaluate it**

```
                    let evaluated = eval(result)
```

> **3. Make an instance.**

```
                    let dynamicComponent = new evaluated();
```

> **4. Invoke render function inside jsx expression**

```
                    <h1>
                        {dynamicComponent.render()}
                    </h1>
```